# Angular 4 Image Onload component variables not updating

Tags: angular, image-loading

I'm trying to use `ngZone` to update component variables after an image has loaded, but the variable is not updating in the template.

```
const downloadingImage = new Image();
downloadingImage.onload = () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.imageLoaded = true;
      this.showImage();
    });
  };

  downloadingImage.src = this.imagePath;
```

I've also tried `ApplicationRef` and `changeDetectorRefs`, but `this.imageLoaded` is not being updated in the component template.

Comment: what do you mean by `is not being updated` and how do you check it?

Comment: In the template I'm applying a dynamic class `[ngClass]="{'active' : imageLoaded}"`, but `imageLoaded` is never changed

Comment: are you sure `onload` is being executed?

Comment: yes, onload is being executed. That code is run, the variable is just not updated in the template

Comment: hmm, this part of code looks ok, maybe you override `this.imageLoaded` somewhere else? in `this.showImage();` maybe?

Comment: FIX: I removed `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from `app.component` and code works as is now